# Ball and ellipse collision

Tags: game-physics

As an exercise I'm trying to implement a pong like game and trying to use a elliptical shapes as the paddles. Can somebody help me to calculate the direction of the ball after the ball and the paddle collide?

[image: what I'm trying to do]
I'm interested in the math part of the calculation, and not some library that can calculate it for me.

Comment: Do you know vector mathematics?  It is an easy problem if so, frustratingly hard if not.

Comment: Might be a better question for http://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RexKerr the biggest problem was how to find the normal vector of the ellipse at the contact point, luckily your answer gives a link, but unfortunately I still quiet don't get it why is the gradient the normal vector

Comment: @shiroyasha - The gradient is the direction of fastest change.  The surface is the direction of zero change (of `(x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2`).  The direction of fastest change is directly away from the surface.  Thus, the normal is in the direction of the gradient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `n` be a unit vector normal to the surface of the ellipse at the point of contact.  (You can find how to calculate such a vector e.g. [here](http://mathhelpforum.com/calculus/5378-normal-vector-point-sphere-ellipsoid.html).)  Let `v` be a vector along which the ball is approaching; it will leave along the vector

```
u = v - 2(v.n)n
```

where `.` is the dot-product.